# How do I return NULL conditionally from a JSON_QUERY

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

How do I return a JSON_QUERY that returns NULL (or no property at all) if the selected value from the sub-query (or left join) is empty?

Here is a simple example (imagine NULL below is a sub-query):

```
SELECT 
    JSON_QUERY((SELECT NULL as SomeColumn 
                FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)) AS Test
```

This returns and empty JSON object - which is not what I want:

```
Test
----------------
{}
```

Since NULL is being returned from the sub-query, I want it to return NULL if the subquery returns NULL, otherwise it should return JSON.

i.e.

When the Subquery returns NULL, the JSON result should be:

```
Test
----------------
NULL
```

When the Subquery returns JSON, the JSON result should be:

```
Test
----------------
{ someColumn: 'some json' ... }
```

How do I do this with a JSON query?

[Edit]

I tried this, thinking I could just do a CASE statement:

```
SELECT 
    JSON_QUERY((SELECT JSON_VALUE('{"SomeColumn":"Test"}', '$') AS SomeColumn 
                FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)) AS Test
```

But this won't select the root. The above returns:

```
Test
------
{}
```

*USE CASE*

The use case that I'm after is this.

When I return a JSON query, I want to be able to return something like this when the address exists:

```json
   { 
      name: 'John',
      address: {
         line1: '123 elm st'
      }
   }
```

OR if there is no address record, I want it to return:

```json
   { 
      name: 'John',
      address: NULL
   }
```

OR

```json
   { 
      name: 'John'
   }
```

I DON'T want it to return

```json
   { 
      name: 'John',
      address: {}
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution to this.

To return NULL properties conditionally when the record from the left join (or subquery) does not exist, use "dot-notation" properties:

```sql
SELECT
    EMP.firstName as [Employee.FirstName],
    EMP.lastName as [Employee.LastName],
    A.Line1 as [Employee.Address.Line1],
    A.City as [Employee.Address.City]
FROM
   Employee EMP
LEFT OUTER JOIN Address A ON A.Id = EMP.AddressId
FOR JSON PATH
```

This will return the following when the employee has an Address:

```json
{
   employee: {
       firstName: 'john',
       lastName: 'smith',
       address: {
          line1: 'elm st',
          city: 'New York'
       }
   } 
}
```

But if the employee does not have an Address record, the query will return this:

```json
{
   employee: {
       firstName: 'john',
       lastName: 'smith'
   } 
}
```

Note:

- You need to make sure all dot notation properties are grouped so that properties and sub properties are together

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you may try the following approach, using the result from `JSON_VALUE()` as a condition:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(
   (SELECT NULL as SomeColumn FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER),
   '$.SomeColumn'
) AS Test
```

Result:

```
Test
----
null
```

But if the JSON output contains information from more than one column, you may count the rows, returned from `OPENJSON()` as a check condition. The result from `OPENJSON()` with default schema is a table, that contains a single row for each `key/value` pair from a JSON text:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM OPENJSON(Json)) THEN Json END AS Test
FROM (VALUES
   ((SELECT NULL AS SomeColumn, NULL AS OtherColumn FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)),
   ((SELECT NULL AS SomeColumn, 123 AS OtherColumn FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER))
) j (Json)
```

Result:

```
Test
-------------------
null
{"OtherColumn":123}
```

Comment: I need to select the entire JSON result, if not null.  Your example is only selecting a single column (SomeColumn).  Is it possible to return the entire JSON result? i.e. if its not null, otherwise return NULL?

Comment: @pixelbits The last example returns the entire JSON. Thanks.

Comment: That returns a string object, not a JSON result. This will be a problem when I try to have tested sub queries that return JSON results, because they will be treated as strings.

Comment: @pixelbits `JSON_QUERY()` returns an `nvarchar(max)` as result.There is no special `JSON` data type. All JSON content is represented as text. But your use case is interesting. I still think, that using `OPENJSON()` as a check condition for "empty" JSON (array or object) is a good option. But when this "empty" JSON is a nested element in a more complex JSON, you'll need to parse the entire JSON again. To be honest,a string-based approach using `REPLACE(Json, '{}', 'null') is also an option`

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
SELECT NULLIF(JSON_QUERY((SELECT NULL as SomeColumn FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)), '{}') as Test
```

Comment: Actually, this does not work.  This `
SELECT NULLIF(JSON_QUERY((SELECT top 1 value from string_split('1,2,3',',') FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)), '{}') as Test ` returns a STRING, not a JSON object.  I need the JSON object.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a `CASE..WHEN` expression :

```
WITH t AS
(
  SELECT JSON_QUERY((SELECT JSON_VALUE('{"SomeColumn":"Test"}', '$') AS SomeColumn 
     FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)) AS Test
)     
SELECT CASE WHEN Test = '{}' THEN 'NULL' ELSE Test END AS Test
  FROM t;


Test
-----
NULL
```

If you want `NULL` value (boolean expression), but not a string `'NULL'`, then use :

`CASE WHEN Test != '{}' THEN Test END AS Test`

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bbba1c812402254e46b62b9849725c5a)</kbd>

Comment: In your above example, your TVF should be returning `{"SomeColumn":"Test"}`.  Since Test is not null, the CASE statement should return `{"SomeColumn":"Test"}`, and not NULL. Your example is returning a NULL result.  I was getting the same thing, when I tried using CASE statements

Comment: It seems like using JSON_VALUE and selecting '$' is not selecting the Root, as I would have expected.

Comment: Hi @pixelbits . First of all, what exactly do you want to get `NULL` or `'NULL'` as a string ?

Comment: I want to get NULL or the JSON object

Comment: @pixelbits As you want to get `NULL` (a boolean expression), then you can use `WITH t AS
(
  SELECT JSON_QUERY((SELECT JSON_VALUE('{"SomeColumn":"Test"}', '$.SomeColumn') AS SomeColumn 
     FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)) AS Test
)     
SELECT CASE WHEN Test != '{}' THEN Test END AS Test
  FROM t`. Consider [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8accaeba1707a73760379ff156a8c1b1)

Comment: That returns a STRING object, not a JSON object. When I start to have nested JSON_QUERYs , it will become a problem because the sub queries will be treated as a string property.  I want it to return a JSON result.

Comment: No @pixelbits , a JSON object is a special formatted STRING. There's no data type `JSON` for SQL Server unlike to Postgres. Have a look at [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cb6b8ccfaa32e3b9a59baabea1a6c44a)

Answer (score 1):

If the JSON_QUERY doesn't locate any value, then it returns NULL.  When you test if JSON_QUERY=N'{}' (when there is nothing located) then it evaluates to FALSE.

Run this and see

```
declare
  @json         nvarchar(max)=N'{ "objects": [ { "shape": "circle" }, {"shape": "square" } ] }',
  @nojson       nvarchar(max)=N'{}';

select json_query(@json, '$.objects[0]'); /* returns { "shape": "circle" } */
select json_query(@json, '$.objects[1]'); /* returns {"shape": "square" } */
select json_query(@json, '$.objects[3]'); /* returns NULL */

select case when json_query(@json, '$.objects[20]')=N'{}' then null else json_query(@nojson) end; 
/* returns {} */

select case when json_query(@json, '$.objects[20]') is null then 'True NULL' else 'False NULL' end;
/* returns 'True NULL' */
```

Answer (score 1):

> I tried this, thinking I could just do a CASE statement:
>
> SELECT
> JSON_QUERY((SELECT JSON_VALUE('{"SomeColumn":"Test"}', '$') AS SomeColumn
> FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)) AS Test
>
> But this won't select the root.

json_value() retrieves **scalar** values (null/boolean/string/number).

```
--"a" value is a scalar/string
select json_value('{"a":"1234"}', '$.a') --> returns 1234

--"a" value is an object
select json_value('{"a":{"anothercolumn": "the value of anothercolumn"}}', '$.a') --> returns null, since a is not a scalar value
```

...hence, `json_value('any json goes here', '$')` will always return NULL, because $elf is object and json_value() can retrieve scalars only.

```
select json_value('{"a":"b"}', '$'), json_value('[1, 2]', '$'), json_value('[{"a":"b"}, {"c":"d"}]', '$') --all NULL
```

for the retrieval of values which are objects or arrays, json_query() is used:

```
select json_query('{"a":{"anothercolumn": "the value of anothercolumn"}}', '$.a') --> returns {"anothercolumn":...}, since value of "a" is an object
--...and....
select json_query('{"a":"b"}', '$'), json_query('[1, 2]', '$'), json_query('[{"a":"b"}, {"c":"d"}]', '$') --each json
```

If you want to retrieve an "object" from a subquery which could return either NULL or a string of a json object, wrap the [code from @iceblade](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63834515/12403612), in a json_query()

```
SELECT JSON_QUERY(
NULLIF(JSON_QUERY((SELECT NULL as SomeColumn FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)), '{}')
) as Test;

SELECT 
     JSON_QUERY (NULLIF((SELECT v.col as SomeColumn 
                FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER), '{}'))  as 'jsonquery'
from (values ('a'), (null), ('b')) as v(col);

SELECT 
     JSON_QUERY (NULLIF((SELECT v.col as SomeColumn 
                FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER), '{}'))  as 'jsonquery'
from (values ('a'), (null), ('b')) as v(col)
for json path, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ISNULL(@JSONPATHQUERY),'{}')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit your answer to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).